# Knockout select list shows correct number of items, but no text or value

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a weird situation where binding my view model to a select list shows the correct number of rows, but the data shown is empty; correct number of option elements, but each has an empty value and text. Underneath the model is correct; selecting a value works fine and upon save, my view model code saves the correct value. It's just nothing is visible. Binding using a function works though; eg this displays correctly:

```
<select data-bind="options: promotionLevels, 
                   optionsText: function(item) {
                       return item().description();
                   }, 
                   optionsValue: function(item) {
                       return item().id();
                   },
                   value: promotionLevel, 
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

While this doesn't:

```
<select data-bind="options: promotionLevels, 
                   optionsText: 'description',  
                   optionsValue: 'id', 
                   value: promotionLevel, 
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

I'm relatively new to knockout and would love to know what the issue is.

Thanks

[Edit]
The data, as generated by the server, is:

```
"promotionLevels":[{"id":"f28391a0-8995-45a4-a360-1dd1ae38861b","description":"Beta"},{"id":"6fb6ad46-fff4-4da8-98ef-4ff469406a6c","description":"Development"},{"id":"f16d044a-4ea6-4001-844e-c8dad6227c04","description":"Production"},{"id":"1da6ac1f-7d31-ba64-fbce-c8623af6464f","description":"QA"},{"id":"bc34a34a-0c89-4215-a001-1ea40433b8a9","description":"Test"}]
```

Dumping the data, once bound via ko, the promotion levels are:

```
"promotionLevels": [
    {
      "id": "f28391a0-8995-45a4-a360-1dd1ae38861b",
      "description": "Beta",
      "__ko_mapping__": {
        "ignore": [],
        "include": [
          "_destroy"
        ],
        "copy": [],
        "mappedProperties": {
          "id": true,
          "description": true
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "6fb6ad46-fff4-4da8-98ef-4ff469406a6c",
      "description": "Development",
      ...
```

I've tried to jsfiddle this, but the dependencies are too great.

[Edit 2]

The page code is:

```
    var mapping = {
        promotionLevel: {
            create: function(ctx) {
                return ko.observable(new Foo.ReferenceDataModel(ctx));
            }
        },
        ...
    };

    var viewModel = @Html.Knockout().ToViewModel(this.Model, @<text>mapping</text>);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#endpointEditor")[0]);
```

And the view model code:

```
Foo.ReferenceDataModel = $.inherit(
Foo.ViewModelBase,
{
    __constructor: function(options) {
        this.__base();

        if (options && options.data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, options.mapping || { }, this);
        } else {
            this.id = ko.observable($.generateId());
            this.description = ko.observable();
        }

        this.save = function(data, e) {
            var self = this;
            var form = $(e.target).parents("form");
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
            if (!$(form).valid()) {
                return;
            }

            if (options.callback) {
                options.callback(self);
            }
        };
    }
});
```

This is an application I've inherited and there's a complex set of models, etc. The base view model just adds default error handling.

Comment: Can you post what is inside the `promotionLevels` and how do you fill it? I guess you have `ko.observable` objects in your `promotionLevels` collection in this case you need to use the functions in the bindings.

Comment: Please post the code where you do the data mapping! So where you take the server returned data and fill in your view model's `promotionLevels` property.

Comment: Sorry, I should know better. I've added more details and I hope this is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have `ko.observable` object's in your `promotionLevels` when you executed this code:

```
var mapping = {
        promotionLevel: {
            create: function(ctx) {
                return ko.observable(new Foo.ReferenceDataModel(ctx));
            }
        },
        ...
    };
```

The [options binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) only supports property names or functions in the `optionsText`.

In your case because the items are observable objects in your array just a plain property name (e.g. 'description') don't work so you need to use the a function `optionsText: function(item) { return item().description(); },`

But if you don't you need the fact that you have observable objects in your collection then modify your mapping to:

```
var mapping = {
        promotionLevel: {
            create: function(ctx) {
                return new Foo.ReferenceDataModel(ctx);
            }
        },
        ...
    };
```

Then the simple property name binding should work:

```
<select data-bind="options: promotionLevels, 
               optionsText: 'description',  
               optionsValue: 'id', 
               value: promotionLevel, 
               optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly I need the object observable. I can't use the function logic either since that breaks other bindings. I think I'll have to rework this entire section. And do some more reading.

Comment: What do you mean on "can't use the function logic either since that breaks other bindings"?